# expand data into unmerged cells

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet that has merged cells in it an I want to unmerge the cells and have the data expanded into the unmerge rows.  How can I do this programetically or through macros?

Answer (score 1):

The way to un-merge cells is (through VBA scripting):

```
Range("A1").MergeCells = False
```